# Newbie in Bootstrap validation: How to validate nl AND be postal codes?

Tags: javascript, bootstrapvalidator

I'm just new at Bootstrap validation and want to validate a zip code (or postal code) for Dutch AND Belgian codes. As you know Dutch codes starts with 4 digits and then 2 letters. Belgians only has 4 digits. None of them start with 0.

Comment: You should use Regular Expressions.

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide a couple of examples of postcodes you need to test?

Comment: Sorry, I'm back.

Belgian postal codes start with 1000 and end with 9999, so 4 digits,
Postcodes in the Netherlands also begin and end like the Belgian ones, exept they follow by 2 letters: for example 1000AB or 1000 AB

Answer (score -1):

Put this in your input field:

```
data-fv-zipcode="true" data-fv-zipcode-country="NL" data-fv-zipcode-message="Ongeldige postcode"
```

and this also in your file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').formValidation({

                }).on('success.form.fv', function(e) {

                }).on('err.form.fv', function(e) {

                }).on('success.field.fv', function(e, data) {

                }).on('err.field.fv', function(e, data) {

                });
});
```

Comment: Why ask the same question again when it 's already asked ? Perhaps Belgian Dude found a way to do it and can help other people with that solution.